# tensorflow eager execution issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning

I am having issues with tensorflow, keras, building models and then calling predict.

My neural network is quite simple and is built as follows:

```
 def create_model():
        
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(24, input_shape=(17, 5), activation = 'relu'))
        model.add(Dense(12, activation = "relu"))

        model.add(Dense(3, activation="linear"))
        model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model
```

However, after compiling, I got:

```
ValueError: Calling `Model.predict` in graph mode is not supported when the `Model` instance was constructed with eager mode enabled. Please construct your `Model` instance in graph mode or call `Model.predict` with eager mode enabled.
```

So on advice of another post I added the following to compile()

```
run_eagerly = True
```

Even after I add this I still get the same error. When investigating I found that when I imported tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
print(tf.executing_eagerly())

2.4.0
True
```

But if I run the same code after compiling:

```
2.4.0
False
```

So at some point eager execution is being switched off automatically, and then I am unable to call predict.

Can somebody help me with understanding why this is happening and the solution?

Comment: For me, it works fine and I do not run into this error (also with tf version 2.4.0). Eager mode is enabled for me and does not switch off either after compiling, no matter whether run_eagerly is set or not in compile().
Could you share your full code?

Comment: @CarterB, Is your issue resolved now? Else, can you share complete code to reproduce your issue, so that we can help you. Thanks!